# How to import pygame into VSCode (Windows 11)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, pygame, background-music

i'm using pygame to add music playing into my code, but for some reason, pygame won't import
message i get (hiding personal/unrelease stuff in ()):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users(name)\Downloads\Python Code(name)*6.03*(unreleased game name)_Prototype_Battle_System.py", line 6, in 
import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

i tried running import pygame and pip install pygame but none worked